# Why p-cyclic extension iff $p^m$-cyclic extension $\forall m$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, kummer-theory

A theorem is stated as follows. For a field $F$ of characteristic $p$, $F$ has a $p$-cyclic extension if and only if for every positive integer $m$, $F$ has a $p^m$-cyclic extension. 
I wonder if there is an elementary proof of it, without too much discussion on Abelian extension theories. All I am acquainted with is basic Galois group and group theory.

Comment: You do know that when the extension degree equals the characteristic, Kummer-extensions need to be replaced with Artin-Schreier? [This standard argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/50062/11619) can be extended to show that $F$ has a cyclic extension of degree $p$ if and only if the mapping $T:F\to F, z\mapsto z^p-z$ is not surjective. Lifting that to cyclic extensions of degree $p^m$ may be a bit more difficult in general. The route I'm aware of would go via Witt vectors, but it sounds like that is one of the pieces you would rather avoid...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I appreciate it. So if I have to prove this as quickly as possible, what’s your advice?  Do I need to finish the whole chapter 3 of Jacobson III？

Comment: Anyway, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2681969/11619) is my take on the "easiest" inductive step of going from a cyclic extension of degree two to one of degree four. All using Witt-vector arithmetic. IIRC the arithmetic details become progressively hairier as $p^m$ grows. OTOH you only want existence. May be that is easier, but I am too ignorant.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen THX very much

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know if there is an easier way. Jacobson is good. If you already worked your way through the corresponding pieces of Kummer theory, then your background is strong enough.