# proof of some statement about finite field extension

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, cyclic-groups, laurent-series

I would like to have some explanation for the following statement

> Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$, and $K((t))$, the field of Laurent series with coefficients in $K$. The Galois group of the polynomial $X^{p^n}-X=t^{-1}$ is isomorphic to the additive group of $F_{p^n}$, i.e. to  $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$.

Another question:

Are there some extensions with Galois group isomorphic to  $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})$ with $n>1$

Comment: It is very rude to just change the problem statement after the problem has been answered.

Comment: @Dedalus I'm sorry i wanted to post a new question, but got confused with this..

Comment: No worries, just wanted to inform you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that $\alpha$ is a root of your polynomial $X^{p^n}-X-t^{-1}=0.$ Then it is obvious that if $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n},$ that $\alpha+a$ is a root as well, since $(\alpha+a)^{p^n}= \alpha^{p^n}+a^{p^n} = \alpha^{p^n}+a.$ So the Galois group is as claimed.

There are finite extensions with Galois groups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ with $n>1.$ This can be done using the Witt polynomials, see for example: [Cyclic Artin-Schreier-Witt extension of order $p^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681736/cyclic-artin-schreier-witt-extension-of-order-p2) .

Comment: Everything you say is, of course, correct. But the answer is missing the piece that the given polynomial is irreducible. That follows from Artin-Schreier theory if we can show that the polynomial has no roots in $K((t))$. Mind you, I'm sure you know how to handle that, but I'm not sure all the readers are aware of all the subtleties. For example, if we replace $t^{-1}$ with $t$, then the series $u=-(t+t^{p^n}+t^{2p^n}+\cdots)\in K((t))$ is a zero of $X^{p^n}-X-t$.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me and posting this comment. You are indeed correct about this point and it is worth pointing out.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen  how one can show that the polynomial is irreducible?

Comment: @Joshfisher This is not hard at all. Have you used the valuation associated to your field, and the non-archimedean property of this valuation? The irreducibility follows immediately from this.

Comment: @Dedalus Do you mean to use the fact that $v_{\mathfrak{P}}(X^{p^n} - X) 
 = v_{\mathfrak{P}}(T^{-1}) = e(\mathfrak{P}/T)$ ?

Comment: @Joshfisher That's the idea. Let $\mathfrak{P}$ be a place above $(t)$. If $u$ is any zero, it follows that $p^n\nu_{\mathfrak P}(u)=-e(\mathfrak{P}|(t))$ and so forth.